# PHP - using static variables to store "client" for later use

Tags: php, cache, static

I had this S3Helper class before such that, every time I called a function to any of its methods (which I haven't shown here, but which do things like upload files to s3 or get temporary s3 links), it called the `getClient()` method and it would make a new client every time.

Now I don't know about the performance hit on that, if calling `new S3Client([])` makes http requests every time it's called, but I supposed it did so decided I'd rather just make the client once and then use the same client for future calls.

So I cached the result in a static variable, and now my `getClient` function checks if the cache exists first, and if it does it returns it, otherwise it makes a new client and sets the cache.

Is this a recommended PHP way of doing things? Can it be improved?

```
<?php // Code within app\Helpers\Helper.php

namespace App\Helpers;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

class S3Helper {
    protected static $client = null;

    private static function getAuth() {
        return [
                'endpoint' => env('S3_ENDPOINT'),
                'key' => env('S3_KEY'),
                'secret' => env('S3_SECRET'),
                'bucket' => env('S3_BUCKET')
            ];
    }

    private static function getClient() {
        if (self::$client) return self::$client;

        $auth = self::getAuth();
        self::$client = new S3Client([
            'region' => 'eu-west-2',
            'version' => '2006-03-01',
            'endpoint' => $auth['endpoint'],
            'credentials' => [
                'key' => $auth['key'],
                'secret' => $auth['secret']
            ],
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => true
        ]);
        return self::$client;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before going through advises just wanted to remind you can alternatively use `Aws\Sdk` class as a client factory.
Sample usage:

```
// The same options that can be provided to a specific client constructor can also be supplied to the Aws\Sdk class.
// Use the us-west-2 region and latest version of each client.
$sharedConfig = [
    'region' => 'us-west-2',
    'version' => 'latest'
];

// Create an SDK class used to share configuration across clients.
$sdk = new Aws\Sdk($sharedConfig);

// Create an Amazon S3 client using the shared configuration data.
$client = $sdk->createS3();
```

Observe [`AWS SDK for PHP`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/getting-started_basic-usage.html) guide, just in case you hadn't yet.
They give a notation there:

> **Note**
>
> We highly recommended that you use the Sdk class to create clients if
>   you're using multiple client instances in your application. The Sdk
>   class automatically uses the same HTTP client for each SDK client,
>   allowing SDK clients for different services to perform nonblocking
>   HTTP requests. If the SDK clients don't use the same HTTP client, then
>   HTTP requests sent by the SDK client might block promise orchestration
>   between services.

---

But, proceeding with your approach, you have a variation of `Singleton` pattern (restricts the instantiation of a class to a single object, which can be useful when only one object is required across the system).
In your case `S3Helper` acting as a *factory* producing/returning the same `S3Client` instance.

To prevent instantiation/cloning of `S3Helper` from the outer code you can *close* `__construct`, `__clone` (and even `__wakeup`) methods:

```
class S3Helper {
    ...
    private function __construct() { }
    private function __clone() { }
```

To eliminate multiple `return` statements in your static `getClient()` method use the following condition (set `client` if it's not set yet):

```
private static function getClient() {
    if (self::$client === null) {   # use strict comparison here
        $auth = self::getAuth();
        self::$client = new S3Client([
            'region' => 'eu-west-2',
            'version' => '2006-03-01',
            'endpoint' => $auth['endpoint'],
            'credentials' => [
                'key' => $auth['key'],
                'secret' => $auth['secret']
            ],
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => true
        ]);
    }
    return self::$client;
}
```